# Python pandas trying to make word count

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I just noticed the tweepy api, I can create dataframe with pandas using tweets object which fetched from tweepy. I want to make a word count df to my tweets. here's my code

```
freq_df = hastag_tweets_df["Tweet"].apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x.split(" "))).sum(axis =0).sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index().head(10)
    
freq_df.columns = ["Words","freq"]
    
print('FREQ DF\n\n')

print(freq_df)
print('\n\n')

 
a = freq_df[freq_df.freq > freq_df.freq.mean() +   freq_df.freq.std()]
    #plotting
fig =a.plot.barh(x = "Words",y = "freq").get_figure()
```

This looks not good as I want because it always starts with "empty space" and "the" word like

```
                         Words   freq
0                               301.0
1    the                        164.0
```

So how I can get desired data, without empty line and some words like 'the'.
Thank you

Comment: `.value_counts()` returns the results sorted descending. So the result is expected, and 'How can I improve my code?' is a bad question here because you get what you expect. To ask a better question add `desired output` result so the community could understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Well,thank you for guiding,

Answer (score 0):

Use can use spaCy library to do it. With this library you can easily remove words like "the","a" known as stop words:

its easy to install : `pip install spacy`

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")


lexeme = nlp.vocab[word]

# process text using spacy

def process_text(text):
    #Tokenize text
    doc = nlp(text)
    token_list = [t.text for t in doc]

    #remove stop words
    filtered_sentence =[] 
    for word in token_list:
        lexeme = nlp.vocab[word]
        if lexeme.is_stop == False:
             filtered_sentence.append(word)

    # here we return the length of the filtered words if you want you can return the list as well
    return len(filtered_sentence)


df = (
    df
    .assign(words_count=lambda d: d['comment'].apply(lambda c: process_text(c) ))
)
```

Comment: Thank you that will help